# Adding Column in Pandas Dataframe Based on column with dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe named df_sample.  It contains three columns.  The first column ('pid') is an identification number of an item.  The second column ('did') is the identification of where the item is located.  The third column ('tid_dict') is a dictionary of where the item should have come from with how many of those items that location had in stock.

I want to check how often (A) the item actually came from one of the locations it should of come from, and (B) if the item came from the location that had the largest quantity. Complicating things is that sometimes the item isn't located as available from any location and other times it comes from somewhere other than where expected.  The following sets up a sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
column_names = ["pid", "tid", "tid_dict"]
data = [['p26CE0DEAC1', 't29', {'t29': 50, 't121': 41, 't140': 33}], ['p5505CB1A96', 't121', {'t156': 48}], ['p1B9E6A73EC', 't256',{}]]

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = column_names)
```

Then I want to add a new column called "loc_check" that checks to see if the value in 'tid' is one of the keys in 'tid_dict'.  Then a second new column named 'inv_check' to see if it was the location with the greatest number of available inventory.

```
df_sample['loc_check'] = #Don't know how to do this part - if 'tid_dict' contains 'tid' = True
df_sample['inv_check'] = #Don't know how to do this part - if 'tid' = 'tid_dict' key with greater value = True
```

So, in the end I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
column_names = ["pid", "tid", "tid_dict", 'loc_check', 'inv_check']
data = [['p26CE0DEAC1', 't29', {'t29': 50, 't121': 41, 't140': 33}, True, True], ['p5505CB1A96', 't121', {'t156': 48}, False, False], ['p1B9E6A73EC', 't256',{}, False, False]]

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = column_names)
```

Any help is appreciated.  Sorry if something isn't clear. I'm a hobbyist that is still beginning to learn python and pandas.

**Follow-up:**

```
column_names = ["pid", "tid", "tid_dict"]
data = [['p26CE0DEAC1', 't121', {'t29': 50, 't121': 50, 't140': 33}], ['p5505CB1A96', 't121', {'t156': 48}], ['p1B9E6A73EC', 't256',{}]]

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = column_names)
```

**How to account for this situation where the answer below returns a True/False even though 't121' has the same number of inventory items available as location 't29'?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use df.apply(lambda function, axis=1) for both the questions

### Code

```
df_sample['loc_check'] = df_sample.apply(lambda x: x['tid'] in x['tid_dict'], axis=1)
df_sample['inv_check'] = df_sample.apply(lambda x:x['tid']==max(x['tid_dict'], key=x['tid_dict'].get) if x['tid_dict'] != {} else False, axis=1)
```

### Output:

```
pid         tid     tid_dict                            loc_check   inv_check
p26CE0DEAC1 t29     {'t29': 50, 't121': 41, 't140': 33} True    True
p5505CB1A96 t121    {'t156': 48}                        False   False
p1B9E6A73EC t256    {}                                  False   False
```

### Explanation

```
df_sample['loc_check'] = df_sample.apply(lambda x: x['tid'] in x['tid_dict'], axis=1)
```

This part simply checks for each row, whether `tid` exists in `tid_dict` and stores the result in column `loc_check`

The next one is a bit more complicated

```
df_sample['inv_check'] = df_sample.apply(lambda x:x['tid']==max(x['tid_dict'], key=x['tid_dict'].get) if x['tid_dict'] != {} else False, axis=1)
```

- `max(x['tid_dict'], key=x['tid_dict'].get)` is used to return the key with the max value in tid_dict.
- `x['tid']==max` is then used to check whether the key returned is the same as 'tid'
- The if check is just to prevent an error when dictionary is empty (like in the third case)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found one bug and I'm trying to figure out how to account for it.  If two locations have the same number of inventory items, it sometimes returns a False.  For example, if 't121' had 50 available items and 'tid' ended up 't121' it returns a False boolean value when I'd like it to be True even if another site had the same number of inventory items available.

Comment: Oh ok then what you can do is get the max value in the dict (should return 50) and then check if tid_dict[tid] = 50. This should fix the bug and work in all cases